# Check whether a list of pairs is unsorted

Tags: list, sml

I have a problem with the following code:

```
fun unsorted cmp ((x, y)::[]) = false
  | unsorted cmp ((x, y)::xx::xs) =
    if cmp(y, xx) = GREATER then true else unsorted cmp (xx::xs)
```

I just want that this function returns `true` if the list is unsorted and `false` otherwise. This should work for a list of pairs compared by the second component.

Here is my correct code for a plain list:

```
fun unsorted' cmp [] = false
  | unsorted' cmp (x::[]) = false
  | unsorted' cmp (x::xx::xs) =
    if cmp(x, xx) = GREATER then true else unsorted' cmp (xx::xs)
```

but where is my mistake with the list of pairs?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your call to `cmp`. Here's the inferred type for your working version of `unsorted`: `('a * 'a -> order) -> 'a list -> bool`

It takes a comparison function (with type `'a * 'a -> order`) and a list containing elements whose type is `'a`. You then pattern match the list using the following pattern: `(x::xx::xs)` so both `x` and `xx` are bound to values of type `'a`, and `xs` is bound to a list of `'a`. Then you call `cmp` with a 2-tuple, which has the type `'a * 'a`: `cmp(x,xx)`.

In your other version, you want to work on a list of pairs (ie a value of type `'a * 'a list`) and so you're using a different pattern: `((x,y)::xx::xs)`. In this case, `x` and `y` are both bound to values of type `'a` but `xx` is bound to a pair, with type `'a * 'a`. So in your call to `cmp`, this is the type of the parameter: `'a * ('a * 'a)`. Remember that in ML all functions take a single argument, and multiple arguments are achieved by passing tuples or currying, both of which you are using in this example. (`cmp` takes a tuple, and `unsorted` is curried)

Try using the following patterns in your new version:

```
fun unsorted cmp ((x,y)::[]) = ...
  | unsorted cmp ((x,y)::(xx,yy)::xs) = ...
```

... and see how far you get as you try to complete the function.

Comment: {fun unsorted cmp ((x,y)::[]) = false
|unsorted cmp ((x,y)::(x',y')::xs) = if cmp(y,y') = GREATER then true else unsorted cmp ((x',y')::xs)}

Comment: That's only going to compare the second element of each pair. I assume you want to check if the list is sorted based on both elements of each pair.

Comment: No i want to compare only the second element of each pair. i think it is correct in this way

Comment: If that's what you want then you're all set!